# Employee Leave types conditions in DJango rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on Hrms application in django rest framework. I've created employee details module now next part is leave management system. Actually my company policy has different leave policies like cl,sl,ml,compo off, and permissions.I'm unable to understand how to make the logic for it and and don't know where to write the logic in serializers or views? Since a newbee i find somewhat difficult. Also when a employee apply a leave it should be requested to T.L. and then should be visible to hr and manager. T.l would give permission and it all should be in application and also in email process. How to make request and approval in rest api also how to send mail using django rest api? Can anyone guide me. If employee select Cl, he got total 12 cl and he can avail monthly once and cl can carryforward upto 3 leaves after that it will expire, then sl means quarterly 2 available, then half day leaves, what will be the logic here and how should i progress?

class LeaveType(models.Model):

```
 Leave_type = (
    ('CL', 'Casual Leave'),
   ('SL', 'Sick Leave'),
   ('ML', 'Medical Leave'),
    ('Comp Off', 'Compensation'),
    ('L.O.P', 'Loss of Pay')
 )


Leave_Choice = (
    ('Full Day', 'Full Day Leave'),
    ('Fore Noon', 'Fore Noon Only'),
   ('After Noon', 'After Noon Only'),

Status_choices = (
   ('Approved', 'Approved'),
     ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),

leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Leave_type)
status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Status_choices, default='Pending')
leave_choice = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Leave_Choice, default='Full Day')

 if leave_type == 'CL':

   total_leave_per_year = 12
   monthly_leave_applicable = 1
   carry_forawrd_monthly_leave = 3

elif leave_type == 'SL':

   Quarterly_days_applicable = 2
   annual_leave_applicable = 8
```

Comment: you are asking multiple question in single query like permissons issue and another is  changing status by different user so your solution will be huge to provide in a single ans

Comment: can u please help me with leave logic dude, that's enough, i will then continue further

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate app for leaves, linked as foreign key field to the main employee.
Then declare leave models, and go with the conditions in the serializer, to allow or not allow employee to apply for leave.
With permissions, you can control the read only or the read/write part of the view.
For sending email, take a look at the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i already created separate app for leave module.so i'm travelling in right path dude, can you please give ideas for only one type leave condition? like how to write the condition for cl leave in serializer since i've given the leave types in choicetype, i'm confused how to create it.

Comment: create models for all types of leaves, then using the validate function in serializers, there u write all the conditions for all types of leaves. def validate(self, data): in the function, the user sent data regarding which leave he will apply, and his user id will be in data field., so you will be able to extract all user data from user model using his id, and then apply conditions here for all types of leaves, if he meets the conditions for his applied leave, only then his leave will be accepted or applied, as you want. This is one of the many possible approaches.

Answer (score 1):

So If you want Logic Here is how you can proceed

Make your first API where the user asks for leave allows a New record to be created in the database and the status must be pending also you should allow some user type to be assigned like Team lead or hr to be mentioned.

so firstly we will have our code as

You will need user as foreign key in your table.

```
LeaveType.objects.create(leave_type="Full_day",status="pending", leave_choice="Cl", assogned_to="some user from foreign key")
```

Now on second step Is our case where the leave can be only seen by some specific people.

For this you need to look after django permissions
suppose we have 3 user type in your system like HR, Team Lead and Project Manager in your user model.

So you need to write your custom permissons class .

You can do this way
from rest_framework import permissions

```
class CanViewLeavePermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # check if user is team lead or not 
        return bool(request.user.is_team_lead)
```

Now we can encorporate  our above class along with permission class list in our view

```
class UpdateLeaveRequestView(UpdateAPIView):
     permisson_class =[IsAuthenticated,CanViewLeavePermission]
```

after this you just need user id, I mean we will create logic to update our api as the id will be taken as slug from url and we can just query the `LeaveType` Model with primary key from url and do send email and update the status and can assign to next person and allow some level of validation if pending leave is already updated.

Hope your understood!

Comment: dude, thanks for your time and guidance, i understand this i just want to know where i should implement th logic you've mentioned above? also can u please suggest how to write different conditions for different leave types and where should i write that? pls help me